# How can I record sound with 16 bits per sample (16 bit depth)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I try to record PCM sound from flash (using Microphone class). I use org.bytearray.micrecorder.MicRecorder helper class. 
In Microphone class I cannot find property like `bitDepth` or `bitsPerSample`. 
I always get 32 bits. 
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: The asker **John812** was able to solve this by using..

`bit16_bytes.writeShort( data.readFloat() * 32767 );` see comments below for context

METHOD #2: Based on my experience with using the LoadPCMfromByteArray method

I have something you could try but I've only used it with an actual 32bit WAVE file and played via the **[LoadPCMFromByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadPCMFromByteArray())** command.

The AS3 Microphone Class records 32 bits. You have to write the conversion of samples to a different bit-depth by yourself. I have no idea how many samples you are processing but the general code below shows you how to convert. Note: `* 512` means use your actual samples amount (example: `* 4096`? or `* 8192`?) If you get the numbers wrong there'll be hiss/distortion so either experiment from small or provide the full details in your question for a more helpful edit/answer.

CONVERT: Assuming your recorded byteArray is called **data**

```
public var bit16_bytes : ByteArray; //will hold the 16bit version

public function convert_to16Bit () : void
{
    bit16_bytes = new ByteArray(); data.position = 0;

    while (bit16_bytes.position < data.length - 4) 

    //if you get noise/distortion try either: 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096 or 8192
    { bit16_bytes.writeShort( data.readInt() * 512 );  } //multiply by samples amount

    data = new ByteArray(); //recycle for re-use
    bit16_bytes.position = 0; //reset or else E-O-File error
    bit16_bytes.readBytes( data ); //copy 16bit back into Data byte-array 

}
```

To run the above function whenever you're ready just add the line `convert_to16Bit();` inside whatever function deals with your "recording complete" situation.

Comment: `data.readInt()` sounds like it should have been `data.readFloat()` but in my experience it gives distorted sound when rounding down numbers from 32bit to 16bit values.

Comment: I used `bit16_bytes.writeShort( data.readFloat() * 32767 )`. Thank you for help.

Comment: Aaah, I love you!!! (no homo). 32767 is the max value of two bytes so it kinda makes sense. What's weird though is a Float/Integer uses up 4 bytes (32 bits) & I dont get how mult by 32767 made it play nicely. My logic was make a 2 byte Short (from the value of four byte Integer). Anyway you've woke me up a little so thanks for the lightbulb moment. Finally I keep saying `data` when I meant `recorded_BA` sorry bout that but I'm sure you understood this if you got it working ok. Updating with your method included..